# Not able to connect from client to a remote pseudo distributed mode hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to configure Hadoop/Hbase in a Single Ubuntu box as Pseudo Distributed mode and want to access hbase remotely. After installation first it was working with localhost settings. when we changed the configuration to ip address Hbase master is not starting. 
my /etc/hosts file

```
10.9.14.9 webserver
```

My hbase-site.xml

```
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
        <description>
            Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
            The port at which the clients will connect.
        </description>
    </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>10.9.14.9</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://10.9.14.9:8020/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rest.port</name>
   <value>60050</value>
  </property>
```

this is the error log - hbase-master.log

> java.net.ConnectException: Call From webserver/10.9.14.9 to webserver:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Can anyone point out what might be the problem. anything i need to look into ?

Have resolved the issue. I have changed the hostnames to IP address in all the configuration files(hbase and zookeeper) except my core-site.xml, in which fs.default.name was configured as hdfs://localhost:8020. After changing localhost to IP address it worked.

Iam able to access the hbase master from a remote client in the browser.

```
> http://10.9.14.9:60010.
```

But when I run the web application from the client I get a different error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for user,,99999999999999 after 10 tries

How to connect from client to a remote pseudo distributed mode hbase?

Comment: can you check whether your region server is dead or not.

Comment: @TomSebastian region server is running. Iam able to connect and run hbase java api in local machine. i get this problem when i try to connect it from remote machine